# phone gap adding contacts problem

Tags: android, cordova, contacts

iam just practicing with phone gap for android app. I found a piece of code in docs.phonegap.com, regarding adding contacts

```
function onDeviceReady() 
 {
     alert('onDeviceReady: PhoneGap1');
     var myContact = navigator.contacts.create({"displayName": "Test User"});
      alert('onDeviceReady: PhoneGap2');
     myContact.gender = "male";
     console.log("The contact, " + myContact.displayName + ", is of the " +  myContact.gender + " gender");
 }
```

When i run this i am getting only the alert box and the name is not added in my contacts. How to add the contacts....

Please tell me how to add data and open the device default contacts...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simon Mac Donald has written a great blog post on contacts with PhoneGap and Android.

http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.com/2011/09/saving-contacts-with-phonegap-android.html

It should help you out as there are a few steps to it.

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer for those of you searching, is that you have to call

```
myContact.save()
```

in order to persist the contact that you just created.